# The purpose of a transaction manager in JTA

Tags: java, transactions

I've just learnt about the transaction manager in JTA, but I've never used it when I need to perform a transaction. Actually, it can be done as follows:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
UserTransaction userTransaction = (UserTransaction)
context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
userTransaction.begin();
//Data operation itself
userTransaction.commit();
```

So, how does the `TransactionManager` become involved?

Comment: All your data operations associated with the transaction manager once its started and will be persisted/destroyed based on commit/rollback!

Comment: @hemanth Hm... interesting. But where is the transaction manager located? Who does provide its implementation? I suspect, it's provided by JTA itself, but I'm not sure about it. Might it provide by, say, JDBC driver or JMS API and so on and so forth?

Comment: JTA will take care of it. All you need to do is set DB properties in some kind of configuration file. A clear definition is at http://simplejta.sourceforge.net/usermanual.html